# why my django form is invalid?

Tags: python, django

I create my form

ROLE is radio button, TEAMS is checkbox

```
class OrganizationMemberForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ROLES = (('member','member'), ('admin','admin'),('manager','manager'),('owner','owner'))
    role = forms.TypedChoiceField(
        choices=ROLES,
        widget=forms.RadioSelect,
    )
    teams = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = OrganizationMember
        fields = ['role']
```

and in my view,I add teams field because I need `choices`value

```
def get_form(self, form_class=None):
    form_class = super(OrganizationMembersDetailView, self).get_form(form_class=None)

    TEAMS = [(team.id, team.id) for team in Team.objects.filter(
        organization=self.model.objects.get(id=self.kwargs.get('pk')).organization)]

    form_class.fields['teams'] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
    choices=tuple(TEAMS),
    widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
    )
    return form_class
```

when i test using my hand the `self.request.POST`is

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['IMkErNAgdNHHcqeisIQclkHvfqwIbR0ycW6ztlvvZ9cufvulmPOlRKQd8PPr4JFe'], 'role': ['admin'], 'teams': ['1', '3']}>
```

So, I want unit test

class OrganizationMemberTest(UserAccountLoginMixin):

```
def test_change_member_role(self):
    response = self.client.post(
        reverse(
            'organization-member-detail',
            kwargs={'slug': self.organization_obj.name, 'pk': self.user_obj.id}
        ),
            {'role':'admin', 'teams':["1","3"]}
    )
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

def test_organization_member_form(self):
    form_data = {'role':'admin', 'teams':['1', '3']}
    form = OrganizationMemberForm(data=form_data)
    self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())
```

but test was failed, because form is invalid.

i change `teams` data

```
// str -> list
data = {'role':'admin', 'teams':['1','3']}
```

but form is invalid too..

why my form is invalid? thank you :)

## UPDATE

IN form.errors `Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.`

when I print(TEAMS) in `get_form`

`[(9, 9)]` was printed so I change the value 1 -> 9

```
    def test_organization_member_form(self):
    form_data = {'role':'admin', 'teams':['9']}
    form = OrganizationMemberForm(data=form_data)
    self.assertTrue(form.is_valid(), form_error)
```

but it has same error...

Comment: Change this     `self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())`, to this `self.assertTrue(form.is_valid(), form.errors)` .. and you'll get the answer right there, in the terminal.

Comment: @slackmart ok, i'll try thank you

Comment: problem solved, when test create object, object's id was generated ramdomly, so I pixed id. thank you everyone :)